# Not retrieve data from QDialog to QMainWindow when hitting Cancel button

Tags: python, pyside2, qdialog

I'm using Pyside2, Python 3.8

I have a `QMainWindow` with a `pushbutton`, when the button is `clicked`, a `QDialog` shows up

[image: My Dialog form]

I want to retrieve the texts in the `QLineEdits` when the Add button is clicked. I've managed to do that using the following code:

```
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.AddButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.CancelButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.ShowDialogButton.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

    def showDialog(self):
        d = Dialog(self)
        d.exec_()
        self.Data = [d.LineEdit1.text(), d.LineEdit2.text(), d.LineEdit3.text()]
        self.func(self.Data)

    def foo(self, foo):
        for txt in foo:
            print(txt)

if __name__== '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As I said, this works, but the problem is that it also works when I hit cancel.

I want the `func` function in my MainWindow class to run only if I hit the Add button and only that.

How Can I achieve that?

Comment: You can connect the add button to the accept slot of the dialog, connect the cancel button to the reject slot. Then in the main window, check the return value of the `exec()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to close QDialogs when connecting to buttons is through [`accept()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#accept) and [`reject()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#reject), and correctly catch the return value from `exec().

```
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.AddButton.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        self.CancelButton.clicked.connect(self.reject)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    # ...
    def showDialog(self):
        d = Dialog(self)
        if d.exec_():
            self.Data = [d.LineEdit1.text(), d.LineEdit2.text(), d.LineEdit3.text()]
            self.func(self.Data)

    # ...
```

You should also consider using [QDialogButtonBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html).

<sub>I suggest you to use capitalized names only for classes, *not* for variable names. Read more on the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)</sub>

Comment: Thanks man ! 

For the QDialogButtonBox, since I'm developping a GUI for Windows user, I think I will give it a pass for the moment, maybe check it later on the project.

Thanks also for the hint about the variables naming, it's thoughtful of you.

Cheers;

Comment: I don't understand, what problem is there that prevents you to use QDialogButtonBox on Windows?